# Issues with Qt's signals and slots behavior with multithreading

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, signals-slots

I'm currently trying to understand how signals and slots in Qt behave with threads.

I've tried to run a small test with the following code:

```
class Worker : public QObject{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    Worker(int _value){value = _value;}
    ~Worker(){};
    int value;

public slots:
    void changeValue(int newValue){value = newValue;}
    void doWork(){
        while(1){
            _sleep(500);
            std::cout << "Value is " << value << std::endl;
            if(value == 0)break;
        }
        emit finished();
    }

signals:
    void finished();
};

class Manager : public QObject{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    Manager(){}
    ~Manager(){};
signals:
    void modifiedValue(int value);
public:
    void changeTheValue(int value){emit modifiedValue(value);}
};
```

Basically, the worker display its `value` member every once in a while, and has a slot with a function that modifies the value.

The manager has the only purpose of emitting a signal with a new value when `changeTheValue` is called, that maps to the slot in Worker that modifies the `value` member.

Then I make my `Worker` class work in a thread the following way :

```
QThread myThread;
Worker myWorker(10);
Manager manager;

myWorker.moveToThread(&myThread);
QObject::connect(&myThread, SIGNAL(started()), &myWorker,SLOT(doWork()));
QObject::connect(&myWorker, SIGNAL(finished()), &myThread, SLOT(quit()));
QObject::connect(&myWorker, SIGNAL(finished()), &myWorker, SLOT(deleteLater()));
QObject::connect(&myThread, SIGNAL(finished()), &myThread, SLOT(deleteLater()));
QObject::connect(&manager, SIGNAL(modifiedValue(int)), 
                 &myWorker, SLOT(changeValue(int)));
myThread.start();

for(int i = 1; i < 10 ; i++){
    _sleep(1000);
    manager.changeTheValue(i);
}
manager.changeTheValue(0);
```

But nothing happens. The value doesn't seem to be changed: output show a dozen lines with `Value is 10`.

What I can't understand is, why does the signal/slot mapping with `Manager::modifiedValue` and `Worker::changeValue` does not seem to work ? Is it only because the thread is currently running the `doWork()`'s loop ? Where does the call to the slots ends up then (queued, discarded, other) ?

I couldn't find much more on how does the signals/slots mechanism work with threads (I only found [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4452328/qt-signals-slots-and-threads) which explains in which thread's call stack does the call to the slot end up, but the link provided in the answer seems outdated and leads to Qt 5 home).

To sum up the questions:

- **Why does the call to the slot that modifies the value does nothing ?**
- **Is it possible to make this work (adding thread-safety wherever necessary) and how ?**

Comment: I hope you have [RTFM](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/threads-qobject.html#signals-and-slots-across-threads).

Comment: Well, unfortunately, this doesn't answer my question at all. I was aware of the 'thread-unsafety' of QObject and their subclasses, and the connections between signals and slot is by default adapted to the context (automatically a direct connection between objects in the same thread, or a queued connection between objects in different threads), but thanks for the link !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are multiple modes of how signals and slots work with threads (you absolutely must use `QThread`s for these to work!). These are documented in the manual:
http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/threads-qobject.html#signals-and-slots-across-threads

The mistake in your code is that the Qt event loop is never called (as `doWork` never returns). For a repeating call you should be using a timer in that thread. Alternatively (NOT the recommended solution) you can call `processEvents` in your infinite loop.

Comment: Well, as explained in the comments above (which already pointed to this link), it doesn't solve my problem (though it's a useful link).

Comment: It does answer the question as given in the title though ;) I just extended the answer to point out why your example does not work.

Comment: Yep you're right, I didn't know what to use as a title that wouldn't end up being 1 km long... +1